# Neo4j :Using cypher query to retrieve auto generated id of the node

Tags: php, neo4j, cypher

I am new to neo4j.

I want to retrieve the auto generated id of the node using a cypher query.

I am using php.

How is it possible?
Also,how do I get just the id of the node in a php variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MATCH (n)
RETURN ID(n) as nodeId
```

See docs: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-functions-scalar.html#functions-id

**EDIT:**

I don't know PHP well but assuming you're using `neo4jphp` I guess the general idea would be something like

```
$client = new Everyman\Neo4j\Client();
$queryString = "MATCH (n) RETURN ID(n) as nodeId";
$query = new Everyman\Neo4j\Cypher\Query($client, $queryString);
$result = $query->getResultSet();
echo $result[0]['nodeId']
```

You will want to read up on `neo4jphp` [here](https://github.com/jadell/neo4jphp/wiki), particularly [how to use cypher](https://github.com/jadell/neo4jphp/wiki/Cypher-and-gremlin-queries). Or you can use [php cURL](https://php.net/curl) with [Neo4j REST API](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api.html).

Comment: Thank you:)Can you tell me how do I display that id on the webpage using php?